# Erlang, override environment

Tags: erlang, config

I have an erlang node with some applications. I want to make my applications to fetch their environments variables from some centralized server (e.g. `hiera server`). Is there any way to override environment variables from `.app` file, replacing it with custom variables obtained from certain place?
Of course, I don't want to make any changes in my applications code.

Comment: Does "don't want to make any changes" automatically exclude using 'set_env/3'?

Comment: I think that `set_env/3` appropriate, but I am searching for way not to keep any such logic in my applications. Think, it is appropriate to use some certain application, that will be loaded before other, and set up any other application.

Comment: `application:get_env/1,2,3` could easily be a bottleneck in highly concurrent scenarios, so it is a good practice to do this only on, say, gen_server init phase, and put configs into it's state. That is why if you will set env after application startup you have to write custom logic to handle config update.

Comment: It's an odd blind spot, majority of config languages allow inlineing env variables in the files which allow this stuff to be set per machine or per proxy. 

Hitting my head with a similiar problem with chicagoboss inside of docker (for mapping linked resources). 

looking like a copy and sed solution for now. Spent too much time on it. If I were more adventures I'd place the logic in boss's rebar_plugin hook.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to completely avoid changes to your application's code, your best bet is to use an external configuration file and copy from your centralized server to each "local" server. If you specify a file path at the end of your application list in sys.config (assuming you're using releases), the BEAM VM will also load this file as additional configuration.

Using this, you can make a file in a location like /etc/my_service/extended.config and have it automatically update using some service or another. Puppet is an example of a tool that could do that part for you; looks like Hiera (which I'm not familiar with) would be another.

For clarity, with this approach, your sys.config file should look like:

```
[
    {my_app1, [
            {my_param1, 1},
            {my_param2, "string"}
        ]},
    {my_app2, [
            ...
        ]},
    "/etc/my_service/extended.config"
].
```

However, that kind of approach has some significant limitations, namely in that the configuration file is only loaded once, and you would have to restart the BEAM VM if you wanted to change it while the service was running. It also works best if you're generating an Erlang release (hence sys.config).

If you're not using an Erlang release and don't have a sys.config file, you can still specify a configuration file using the `-config` command-line parameter with `erl`

The best approach, IMO, would require you to make some minor modifications to your application. I would advise storing your parameters in a distributed mnesia table (or any other database, really, so long as you can easily query it). Subsequently, replace your `application:get_env/2,3` calls with a call to a function you define which checks the database you are storing settings in before falling back to `application:get_env/2,3`.

For instance:

```
-record(setting, {key, value}).
get_setting(App, Key) ->
    get_setting(App, Key, undefined).

get_setting(App, Key, Default) ->
    case mnesia:dirty_read(settings, {App, Key}) of
        [] ->
            application:get_env(App, Key, Default);
        [_ = #setting{value = Value}] ->
            Value
    end.
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks for such detailed answer, I think, most appropriate for me is generate config files from hiera and copy this config to each local server before BEAM starts up.